# Infinite dimensional vector space of solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exercise from Stein with partial differential operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139763/exercise-from-stein-with-partial-differential-operator)

Let $S$ be a linear partial differential operator in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n \geq 2$ and consider the vector space of $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $Sf = 0$. Why is this vector space not finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2):

A function can be constant in one direction and non-constant in another.

For instance, any smooth function of $y$ like $e^y$ or $\sin(y)$ can be thought of as a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is smooth and annihilated by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, and that's an infinite dimensional vector space of two-variable smooth functions.

Comment: How does this help answer the question for a *general* linear partial differential operator?